# Interference with audio playback in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a recyclerview that plays a series of audio files.

https://ul.uncox.com/qa-image/65873409abe59520d537dcef733e571aa4a1d93e.png

My problem now is that if one music is played and I play another, they both play together.

```
public class AdapterSong extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSong.viewHolder> {

  Context context;
  List<ModelSong> model;
  String url_audio;
  MediaPlayer mediaplayer;

  public AdapterSong(Context context, List<ModelSong> model) {
    this.context = context;
    this.model = model;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public AdapterSong.viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rec_song, parent, false);
    return new AdapterSong.viewHolder(view);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdapterSong.viewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ModelSong data = model.get(position);
    holder.tittle.setText(data.getTittle());
    holder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
          url_audio = "http://kanoonmedia.ir/files/sorod/" + data.getFile();
          mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
          mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
          mediaplayer.setDataSource(url_audio);
          mediaplayer.setLooping(true);
          mediaplayer.prepare();


        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mediaplayer.start();
      }
    });

    holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        holder.play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mediaplayer.stop();

      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return model.size();
  }

  public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tittle;
    CircleImageView play, stop;

    public viewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      tittle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_tittle_song);
      play = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_play_song);
      stop = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_stop_song);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `mediaplayer.setLooping(false);`

or if you need loop until user press stop/next, than you should use same copy of mediaPlayer for stop which you use for play. With that will help `mediaPlayer` in parent class or more wise using what calls `Class factory`. https://www.journaldev.com/1392/factory-design-pattern-in-java

Comment: hi. had no effect